# Reprojected Shapefile does not align with OpenLayers Plugin

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, overlay, qgis-openlayers-plugin, australia

I am based in NSW, Australia.  I have a shapefile that when I underlay with the OpenLayers plugin (Google satellite), the shapefile is skewed despite all my efforts to correct it.  I changed the project properties to GDA 94 and GDA 94 MGA 56, as well as re-saving the shapefile as WGS 84 EPSG:3857 to match the OpenLayers plugin.  Nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help?  Is it the original shapefile?

Comment: what software are you using to display your shapefile? To be clear, are you loading your shapefile into a OpenLayers.Layer.Vector object or are you using OSM basemap inside a software?

Comment: I am using QGIS 2.4

Answer (score 1):

Supposed you are using QGIS:

**Project** CRS must be EPSG:3857 when youn intend to use the Openlayers plugin.

The **layer** CRS may have other CRS, as long as `On-the-fly-reprojection` is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your response Andre.  I have tried that with no avail. It is still skewed.

Comment: No matter what projection I assign the layer or project it is still skewed

Comment: Can you share the shapefile, or parts of it via dropbox?

Comment: Hi Andre, after a few hours of stuffing around with it I worked it out. I re-added the shapefile into the project again and assigned it to AGD84 eventhough the metadata stated AGD66.  This seemed to fix the problem.  The shapefile is now better aligned with openlayer plugin.  Thanks for your help I do appreciate it.